# GODOT - How can I stop the player from hitting the default walls in GODOT and instead keep going

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot, gdscript

I am making a platformer game and I dont know how to make the player to dont collide with those default walls! Ive already setted the camera follow but now my player is getting stuck on those default walls!

Here´s the player movement code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D



const GRAVITY = 600
const WALK_SPEED = 200
const JUMP_FORCE = 350

var velocity = Vector2()
var screen_size


func _ready():
    screen_size = get_viewport_rect().size


func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += delta * GRAVITY

if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    velocity.x = -WALK_SPEED
elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
    velocity.x = WALK_SPEED
else:
    # velocity.x = 0
    # smoothen the stop
    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, 0, 0.1)

if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up") and is_on_floor():
    velocity.y = -JUMP_FORCE
 
velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

# prevent player going out of screen
position.x = clamp(position.x, 0, screen_size.x)
position.y = clamp(position.y, 0, screen_size.y)
```

Please help!
The player just gets blocked as shown in the image!
Like I cant advance more from that position idk why. Sorry my english is bad.

Please help, thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

My Player gets stuck when he reaches that blue line when the game is running. I just want to desactivate that. Do you know any way?

Comment: I'd like to help but not sure what you mean by 'those default walls', also the image you refer to is missing from the question!

Comment: I have updated it sorry!

Comment: some code where you are checking collision or movement would also be useful (perhaps in your KinematicBody2D for your player) and also how the collision shapes are implemented in the wall and the player?

Comment: My Player gets stuck when he reaches that blue line when the game is running. I just want to desactivate that. Do you know any way?

Comment: Is the player getting stuck or the camera? There aren't any default walls, but you can configure limits for the camera. Are you using a template? How does the code to move the player looks like?

Comment: No im not using any template.  So... when the player tries to pass by that "wall", it just dont move, like I can move back and do everything fine, but when I try to pass by that line the player can´t as well as the camera. I think its because the player can only move to the size of the screen, because when I put the game in FullScreen, I can move much further. About the code, imma update the post! Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think its because the player can only move to the size of the screen, because when I put the game in FullScreen, I can move much further.

Right there in the code is what you describe:

```
# prevent player going out of screen
position.x = clamp(position.x, 0, screen_size.x)
position.y = clamp(position.y, 0, screen_size.y)
```

If you don't want to limit the player to the screen, remove that code.

*On a similar note, make sure you have a camera following the player. The simplest way to do it is to put a `Camera2D` as child of the player and set its `current` property to `true`.*

Comment: Oh my god! This is what happens when you take a code from the internet and dont even read it! Im so dumb. Thank you a lottt tho! :)